# Redirect loop in Chrome

Tags: php, mysql, apache, session, authentication

I have just setup Apache and Mysql on my server and trying to create a website with a session based login system. I have followed the tutorial from this link: http://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/

Everything seems fine except when testing the login. Once I have entered a correct username and password combination it fails to login succesfully as Chrome shows an error as such

[image]

I do not have an .htaccess file on my server, and I am sure the login details are correct as the URL shown on the address bar is pointing to the dashboard page (profile.php according to the tutorial) supposed to be shown on a successful login.

The source code for the login.php page where the querying of the database is done is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("company", $connection);
// SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
$query = mysql_query("select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'", $connection);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
header("location: profile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
} else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
}
}
?>
```

The login page (index.php) is as follows:

```
<?php
include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script

if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
header("location: profile.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Form in PHP with Session</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<h1>PHP Login Session Example</h1>
<div id="login">
<h2>Login Form</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>UserName :</label>
<input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text">
<label>Password :</label>
<input id="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" type="password">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
<span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When trying to login using Internet Explorer, IE gets stuck on trying to load the next page (just shows the waiting message with the loading icon).

I have chmod my files based on the link: http://fideloper.com/user-group-permissions-chmod-apache
(replaced /var/www with /var/www/html where all my files are at).

EDIT: Code for profile.php (and session.php)

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Home Page</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="profile">
<b id="welcome">Welcome : <i><?php echo $login_session; ?></i></b>
<b id="logout"><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></b>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

session.php

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("company", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from login where username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

Comment: So what url(s) does chrome try to redirect to?

Comment: address bar shows correct url (profile.php) the dashboard page where user is to be redirected once login is successful

Comment: Address bar shows the current address only. Take Fiddler and see if it's a redirect loop on `profile.php` only or it's an implicit loop between several urls.

Comment: Then there is something wrong on that profile.php page. Consider posting the code of that page too.

Comment: can you show the code of `profile.php` ?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it is only on profile.php  http://imgur.com/He7QWZa

Comment: Supply the code in `profile.php`

Comment: found the problem. wasn't passing the mysql password on session.php (i was passing it on login.php though). Should i delete this question? Solution seems to be very simple